# Unexpected little gap between tooltip and absolutely positioned triangle

Tags: css, reactjs, browser, position, styled-components

I am using Tooltip Component which is rectangle with absolutely positioned `::before` element.Tooltip can be displayed on the top, on the left, on the right and on the bottom of the element it is attached to (the decision depends on free space around the element). The problem is that sometimes triangle of tooltip is displayed with little-little gap between it and the rectangle (especially when tooltip is displayed on the top or on the left of the element). I have no idea why this happens. To my mind one css property is responsible for that (`left, right` and etc.). But still sometimes we can see a gap. Please, give me an idea why this could happen. Is it bug of Browser or not? (want to add that in Firefox, for example, there is sometimes a gap when tooltip displayed on the bottom even). Or where should i search for the answer? I will attach styles of tooltip and images where you can see the problem.

Everything is OK (tooltip on bottom - Chrome)

[image: Everything is OK (tooltip on bottom - Chrome)]

Tiny gap between triangle and tooltip - Chrome

[image: Tiny gap between triangle and tooltip - Chrome]

320% zoom in firefox
[image: 320% zoom in firefox]

330% zoom in firefox

[image: 330% zoom in firefox]

```
const TailsMap = {
  bottom: css`
    &::before {
      border-width: 0 4px 4px 4px;
      border-color: transparent transparent ${colors.tooltipBackground} transparent;
      top: -4px;
      left: calc(50% + 6px);
    }
  `,

  top: css`
    &::before {
      border-width: 4px 4px 0 4px;
      border-color: ${colors.tooltipBackground} transparent transparent transparent;
      bottom: -4px;
      left: calc(50% + 4px);
    }
  `,

  left: css`
    &::before {
      border-width: 0 4px 4px 4px;
      border-color: transparent transparent ${colors.tooltipBackground} transparent;
      transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-50%);
      top: calc(50% - 1px);
      right: -4px;
    }
  `,
  right: css`
    &::before {
      border-width: 0 4px 4px 4px;
      border-color: transparent transparent ${colors.tooltipBackground} transparent;
      transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-50%);
      top: calc(50% - 1px);
      left: 6px;
    }
  `
}

export const Tooltip = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  z-index: ${layerLevels.levelImportant};
  left: ${({ cords: { cords }, offsetPosition }) => (cords.left + (offsetPosition.left ?? 0)).toFixed(4)}px;
  top: ${({ cords: { cords }, offsetPosition }) => (cords.top + (offsetPosition.top ?? 0)).toFixed(4)}px;
  animation: ${showing} 0.3s ease-in-out forwards;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-left: -10px;
  }

  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    border-bottom-width: 6px;
  }

  ${({ cords: { place } }) => TailsMap[place || "bottom"]}
  ${({ cords: { place } }) =>
    place === "top" || place === "bottom"
      ? `${place === "top" ? "transform: translate(-50%, -50%);" : "transform: translate(-50%);"}}`
      : place === "left"
      ? "transform: translateX(-100%);"
      : ""}
```

```css
div { 
    font: 300 18px/26px "Yantramanav","Helvetica","Noto",serif;
    color: #454545;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.004);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.css-m2mqou {  
    font: 300 18px/26px "Yantramanav","Helvetica","Noto",serif;
    color: #454545;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.004);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}
    
.css-1sxz9q5 {
    font: 300 18px/26px "Yantramanav","Helvetica","Noto",serif;
    color: #454545;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    line-break: auto;
    text-align: start;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-break: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: normal;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    left: 375.4px;
    top: 201.2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
    
.css-1sxz9q5::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border-width: 0px 4px 4px;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgba(50, 62, 68, 0.9);
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-50%);
    top: calc(50% - 1px);
    right: -4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.css-1sxz9q5::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    border-bottom-width: 6px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.css-194sc38 {
    font: 300 18px/26px "Yantramanav","Helvetica","Noto",serif;
    font-style: normal;
    line-break: auto;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: normal;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: pre;
    line-height: 17px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    word-break: break-word;
    font-family: Yantramanav;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.004) 1px 1px 1px;
    text-align: center !important;
    background-color: rgba(50, 62, 68, 0.9) !important;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s !important;
    padding: 8px !important;
    border-radius: 2px !important;
    max-width: 300px !important;
    min-width: min-content !important;
 }
 
.css-194sc38::after {
    content: "";
    border-top-color: rgba(50, 62, 68, 0.9) !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="css-m2mqou">
    <div class="css-1sxz9q5">
      <div class="css-194sc38">The average amount of time callers 
spent on hold with agents
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @isherwood Is there option to copy all the styles attached to block of html code. Because it is not easy task to copy everything correctly)

Comment: No, you'd have to open the stylesheet or look at the embedded style element. You should be able to click into a rule in the browser and easily find it.

Comment: Does the gap come and go if you zoom to different levels?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, it does

Comment: The problem is like a rounding error, the system has difficulty deciding how to map part CSS pixels onto the several screen pixels that make up one CSS pixel on modern screens. Sometimes a screen pixel gets ‘left behind’.

Comment: @AHaworth Sounds reasonable. Thank you. And do you have any idea how I can fight with this behaviour)

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example